# Can popupmenubutton return Dialog?

Tags: flutter, dialog, popupmenu

I have been trying to make a dialog popup when pressing a popupmenubutton, however it does not seem to work, I run the app in debug mode through chrome as my Laptop is unable to run in debug mode through androud studio emulator.

```
 child: Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(31, 31, 47, 1),
    appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            onSelected: (value) {
              print(value);
            },
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text('Cancel'),
                  onTap: () {BackdropFilter(
                 filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
                child: Dialog(
                 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                 backgroundColor: Color(Color.getAlphaFromOpacity(0.5)),
                  child: _dialogContent(),
                  )
               );
                  },
                ),
                ];
            },
          ),
        ], ),


  Widget _dialogContent() {return SimpleDialog(
title: Text('Enter Cancel Code'),
                     children: <Widget>[
                    //  TextFormField()
                    ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
              child: Text('Okay')),
                      ],);}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why I doesn't work is because you didn't specify a value to your `popupMenuItem` thats why your `onSelected` property dont know what to do when you tapped on an item, so to make it work you need to do like so

```html
      PopupMenuButton<int>(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  onSelected: (value) {
                    if (value == 0) {
                      showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => _dialogContent,);
                    }
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return [
                      const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                        value: 0,
                        child: Text('Show dialog'),
                      ),
                    ];
                  },
                ),
```

:

if you want to use the `onTap` property of the PopupMenuItem, you need to delay your showDialog because  when you call the onTap, it is triggering the `Navigator.of(context).pop()`. So it looks like nothing is happening when you try to show dialog because its being popped immediately. So to make it work, you need to do it like so:

```html
            PopupMenuButton<int>(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return [
                              const PopupMenuItem<int>(
                                value: 0,
                                child: Text('Show dialog'),
                                onTap: ()=> Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds:1),(){
                                showDialog(context:context, builder: (context)=> _dialogContent)
                                })
                              ),
                            ];
                          },
                        ),
```

Comment: I completely forgot to do this, damn, I will do this and let you know how it went

Comment: @alphacruze happy to help. consider upvoting if you think it helped you. and can hit the checkmark to marked it as answered.